# Find installation path in linux

Tags: linux

When doing

```
apt-get install <service-name>
```

or

```
 yum install <service-name>
```

services are automatically installed. How to find exact path where any service is installed and their configuration files??

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few ways to find this but I usually prefer following

```
whereis <service-name>
e.g whereis java
```

and to find from which path program is using, I use

```
which <service-name>
e.g which java
```

Comment: Does this work centOs as well?? can i change the default installation path?

Comment: yes it works on Centos as well as Ubuntu and other Linux Distros.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `apt-get`, install `apt-file` program and you can list the contents of the package:

```
sudo apt-file update
apt-file list package_name
```

This will show all the files that will be installed by a package, binaries, configuration files, systemd startup files, etc.

If you use `yum`, install `yum-utils` and use `repoquery`:

```
repoquery -l package_name
```

Comment: Could you please explain the downvote?

Answer (score -1):

Suppose service name is nginx then you can find it in `/etc/nginx/` on `ubuntu`.

Comment: can we change the installation path ?? what is for centos ??

Comment: Find "it"? The config files, maybe. Not binaries or other files.

Comment: On centos you can check path using commands given by slashRahul. As per my knowledge you can not change installation path while installing by apt-get. Software components are not installed in a single directory, but across many folders like binaries stay in /usr/bin/, /bin, /sbin, Configuration in other directories.