# How to find where nginx installs?

Tags: linux, nginx

Sorry for that I am not familiar with linux.
I tried to search the answer and tried this command:

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

But I only get the result like this:

```
nginx: master process ./sbin/nginx
```

I got confused because as far as I know, dot means current directory where I execute linux command.

But I can not find sbin/nginx from current folder.
So where I can find nginx and where is the configuration it actually works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find installation path in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409312/find-installation-path-in-linux)

Comment: There is also a duplicate at Unix&Linux: [How to find the installation path for a software under linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19369)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these commands:

```
whereis nginx
which nginx
find / -name nginx.conf
```